# Saving an array leads to empty file in c

Tags: c

```
void loadFile(int array[ROW][COL]){
    FILE *gradesBin;

    gradesBin = fopen("grades.dat", "rb");
    if (gradesBin == NULL){
        printf("No file found.\n");
        fclose(gradesBin);
        return;
    }
    else {
        fread(*array, sizeof(int[ROW][COL]), 1, gradesBin);
    }

    fclose(gradesBin);
    return;
}

void saveFile(int *array, int i){
    FILE *gradesBin;

    gradesBin = fopen("grades.dat", "wb+");
    if (gradesBin = NULL){
        printf("File Error\n");
        fclose(gradesBin);
        exit(1);
    }
    //stores the data into the data file
    fwrite(*array, sizeof(int[ROW][COL]), 1, gradesBin);
    fclose(gradesBin);
}
```

Here's the code I'm having trouble with. The loadFile function is called at the beginning of the array, and the saveFile is called at the end.
The array is initialized in main to be filled with NULL values, and when I end the program, it'll create a new grades.dat file if one doesn't exist, but the file is always empty.

Comment: your if statement in saveFile should be `gradesBin == NULL` not `gradesBin = NULL`

Comment: You really should turn on -Wall on your compiler, it would've caught that.

Comment: also, your reading and writing of files is atrocious, you really should look at how to divide things up in C more carefully

Comment: As Pablo mentioned, take a look at:  `size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)`

Comment: It should be `fread(array, sizeof(int[ROW][COL]), 1, gradesBin);` and the same goes for the `fwrite`.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting the major issues here:

`if (gradesBin = NULL){}` should be `if (gradesBin == NULL){}`

The first code sets `gradesBin` to `NULL`, and then checks if that was successful, which it was, always running that section.

---

`fread(*array, sizeof(int[ROW][COL]), 1, gradesBin);` should be `fread(array, sizeof(int[ROW][COL]), 1, gradesBin);`

and

`fwrite(*array, sizeof(int[ROW][COL]), 1, gradesBin);` should be `fwrite(array, sizeof(int[ROW][COL]), 1, gradesBin);`

No need to dereference here.

---

```
void loadFile(int array[ROW][COL]){
    FILE *gradesBin;

    gradesBin = fopen("grades.dat", "rb");
    if (gradesBin == NULL){
        printf("No file found.\n");
        fclose(gradesBin);
        return;
    } else {
        fread(array, sizeof(int[ROW][COL]), 1, gradesBin);
    }

    fclose(gradesBin);
    return;
}

void saveFile(int *array, int i){
    FILE *gradesBin;

    gradesBin = fopen("grades.dat", "wb+");
    if (gradesBin == NULL){
        printf("File Error\n");
        fclose(gradesBin);
        exit(1);
    }
    fwrite(array, sizeof(int[ROW][COL]), 1, gradesBin);
    fclose(gradesBin);
}
```